# Titanium with a remote database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, titanium

How is it possible to connect my Titanium project with a external / remote database.

Most tutorials and information I see are about local databases.
I just want to connect with an external online database so I could update a record.

Regards

Comment: No you cannot connect to remote db from Titanium, that is why we use server-side languages(webservices).

Comment: Hello Turtle. Do you have an example for me?

Answer (score 0):

You can get and set information in a mysql database if you write some php and hit up those urls, appending them with values to set, returning values to get.

See Gregor's post here; https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/51201/how-to-create-mysql-query-from-titanium-mobile